# Git: modify file in a previous commit

Tags: git

Suppose I have the following file **file.txt** which contains:
`124`
and suppose I already committed it (**commit A**).
Then I go on by adding 5 to **file.txt** and I commit it (**commit B**). The file now is:
`1245`
Then I add 6 to **file.txt** and commit it (**commit C**). The file now is:
`12456`
Now I suppose that I notice that there is a bug to fix, I have to add 3 to make **file.txt** become:
`123456`
My question is: is there a better way to do it other than creating a branch on the first commit (**commit A**), fixing the bug and then doing merge?
What I would like to have is a simple correction to the file (maybe by checking out first commit) and see this correction updated to its children commits.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why not branching from the current branch and fixing that?

Comment: Because it makes history dirty

Comment: The history is part of us :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just make all changes to the file.

Do a `git rebase -i head~5`(i am using 5 as an example. You should use a number equal to the number of commits from head which contain all your changes on that same file)

Now `squash`  all the commits that have worked on the file into one commit.

Comment: I think this solution is a bad practice. The best solution is to branch from the commit, make the change and then merge it (or maybe cherry-pick it) back to the first branch (especially if you pushed it somewhere along the way)

Comment: Well yeah but then i just posted what i felt it would help answer the question. :)   Dont know why the downvote though .Anything that changes history is BAD i agree.

Comment: Nothing personal of course. I just don't think that if someone is looking for an answer we should give it to him at any cost. The git way is to branch and merge in that case (he can delete the branch afterwards of course.

Comment: Hmm ok. :)  Agree.

Answer (score 2):

if it's a private branch, you can do as @som-bhattacharyya said. If it's a public branch, you should never rewrite it, so rebase or amend are not viable options.

You should create a hotfix branch from commit C and do the fix. it's no shame to have a bug fixed some time after introduced with some commits in the middle, it happens to everyone :)